# ActiveRecord is not updating ID for polymorphic association accessed by :through after saving object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I'm trying to create a set of models in which user's profile has one address assigned but user can have many addresses in his virtual "address book". The user should be able to pick up the default address from all his addresses and assign it to profile as home_address.

The addresses can have many types which differs. There are home addresses but there are also company and bank addresses that have additional fields. That's why I have to use polymorphism.

I created the models:

```
class Addresser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :addressable,  :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :address,      :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :address_id, :address_type

end

class HomeAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :addresser, :as => :address, :inverse_of => :address

  attr_accessible :name, :city, :zip, :street, :state, :country

end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one     :home_address,  :through => :addresser,
                              :source => :address, :source_type => 'HomeAddress', 
                              :autosave => true

  has_one     :addresser,     :as => :addressable, :inverse_of => :addressable, 
                              :autosave => true

  attr_accessible :name, :gender

end
```

Everything is working almost fine but Rails is not updating one of the fields after saving the models:

```
profile_data = {
    :name    => 'Some User',
    :gender => 'm'
}

address_data = {
   :street => 'Streeting 7',
   :country => 'PL',
   :city => 'New Rails',
 }

my_profile = Profile.new(profile_data)

=> #<Profile id: nil, name: "Some User", gender: "m", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

my_address = HomeAddress.new(address_data)

=> #<HomeAddress id: nil, street: "Streeting 7", city: "New Rails", country: "PL

my_profile.home_address = my_address

INSERT INTO `addressers` (`address_id`, `address_type`, `addressable_id`, `addressable_type`)
VALUES (NULL, 'HomeAddress', NULL, 'Profile')
COMMIT

=> #<HomeAddress id: nil, name: "Sir Adam Rails", street: "Streeting 7", city: "New Rails", country: "PL">

my_profile.save!

 INSERT INTO `profiles` (`created_at`, `name`, `gender`, `updated_at`)
 VALUES ('2012-06-23 10:07:51', 'Some User', 'm', '2012-06-23 10:07:51')

 INSERT INTO `home_addresses` (`city`, `country`,`street`)
 VALUES ('New Rails', 'PL', 'Streeting 7')

 UPDATE `addressers` SET `addressable_id` = 1 WHERE `addressers`.`id` = 1

 COMMIT
=> true
```

In the above the addressable_id is updated but address_id is not. That causes the constraint to be invalid and unusable after reopenning database session:

```
Addresser.first

SELECT `addressers`.* FROM `addressers` LIMIT 1
=> #<Addresser id: 1, address_id: nil, address_type: "HomeAddress", addressable_id: 1, addressable_type: "Profile">
```

Since address_id is nil, the profile.home_address cannot be found.

Can I fix this without manually updating the address_id of addressable?

The architecture of my app requires me to build the whole object with some initial settings and do the atomic save, so building address and saving it before user (which owns the profile) is created is a weak option.